# Ask Ubuntu ads appear only as "Stack Android App" ads, not showing community ads

Tags: support, bug, advertising

It seems that in the change to display the ads for the android app, I am now only seeing ads for the android app on Ask Ubuntu.

This has the unfortunate side effect that none of the community ads are being displayed at the moment.

Wondering if a bit got flipped or if this is a purposeful campaign taking complete place of the community ads for a time.

It seems to be fine on other stack sites - so that should rule out a *browser* specific problem, but here I see:

[image]

Comment: 15 out 15 page I visited had the android ad on AU. Other SE sites looks just fine

Comment: Maybe you should use the SE Android App

Comment: the thing is - I am! Does it want me to use it all the time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ack! Well that was a rate of serving higher than I expected and intended. Sorry for terrifying you by displaying David's angry face at you so much.

Fixed!

Thank you for bringing this to our attention and please let me know if you still see a crazy high serving rate in the future.